# Looking for tools to summarize or quiz from large PDF/text files

Tags: gratis, text-processing

Claude AI chatbot provides the ability to summarize PDF/texts. But it still has a limit, usually if one wants to create a summary of a book the pdf/text file has a lot of words exceeding the limit placed by Claude.
Are there any other good tools that can create a summary of a pdf/text or quiz you from a pdf/text

Comment: you have to send the content to ChatGPT in chunks, see [Translate a book writen in LaTeX from Slovenian into English](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/book_translation/translate_latex_book.ipynb) : "To translate the book, we will first split the book into chunks, each roughly a page long, then translate each chunk [from Slovenian] into English, and finally stitch them back together."